# How to access the test step request of another test case in the same test suite

Tags: testing, groovy, soapui

I have 1 Test Suite, which contains 2 Test Cases. In first Test Case, I have a SOAP Test Request. I want to access to this Test Request and I want exactly request of this Request! 
I used:

```
def myTestSuite=testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteByName("To internal")
def myTestCase=myTestSuite.getTestCaseByName("Create&Repeat")
def myTestStep=myTestCase.getTestStepByName("create")
log.info (myTestStep.getAssertableContent()) //this step to see what i get
```

So, in this way everything I get is response, but I want request!

How can I do that?

Comment: Are the both test cases in same suite?

Comment: @Rao As i wrote, yes, they are both in the same suite, called "To internal"

Comment: Nikita, please check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code to get the test step request of the same test suite, but different test case:

**GroovyScript:**

```
//Get the test step create which is present in Create&Repeat test case of the same suite
def step = context.testCase.testSuite.testCases['Create&Repeat'].testSteps['create']
log.info step.httpRequest.requestContent
```

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what i needed. Where do you get that info? I searched SOAPUI API to find methods but not so well...

Comment: Available in API only, otherwise no way I would get it. By the way, you won't find it as it is because, the one I provided is groovified statement. Glad it helped